# R Replacing NAs with different date values in the same row across multiple time columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a `dataset` that has some `NAs` in the `time` columns as shown in the sample data below. Usually when I am modifying row values of a single column I use:

```
df["195", "Date_Received"] = "9/1/2017"
```

But now I want to add values to the NA rows in the desired columns without having to write the above statement multiple times.

Please note that the columns in the original are in date format using `lubridate`.

What could be a `tidy` way of doing this in `R`?

Dummy Data

```
Date = c("2021-11-01", "2021-11-04", NA, "2021-11-15", NA)

Year = c(2021, 2021, NA, 2021, NA)

Month = c(11, 11, NA, 11, NA)

Day = c(01, 04, NA, 15, NA)
```

Desired Output

```
    Date         Year  Month Day
    2021-11-01   2021  11    01
    2021-11-04   2021  11    04
    2021-11-12   2021  11    12
    2021-11-15   2021  11    15
    2021-12-02   2021  11    02
```

Code

```
library(tidyverse)

df = data.frame(Date, Year, Month, Day)

# Replacing NAs with date values....
```

Comment: Why should be the 3rd date be 2021-11-12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where you are getting your date values for rows 3 and 5, but you if you have a vector of the dates you want, you can just assign them directly

```
df = data.frame(Date=Date)
df[is.na(Date),"Date"] <- c("2021-11-12","2021-12-02")
```

Output:

```
        Date
1 2021-11-01
2 2021-11-04
3 2021-11-12
4 2021-11-15
5 2021-12-02
```

You can then create the year/month/day columns if necessary:

```
df %>%  mutate(Year = year(Date), Month = month(Date), day=day(Date))
```

Output:

```
        Date Year Month day
1 2021-11-01 2021    11   1
2 2021-11-04 2021    11   4
3 2021-11-12 2021    11  12
4 2021-11-15 2021    11  15
5 2021-12-02 2021    12   2
```

Comment: I am getting this error `Error occurred for column Date.
x Can't convert <character> to <date>.
Backtrace:
  1. base::[<-(*tmp*, "193", "Date", value = <chr>)
 17. tibble <fn>(<vctrs___>)`

Comment: @Mandalorian, it seems to work on the dummy data you provided. Are you using something other than the dummy data? If so, and you haven't figured out the problem, perhaps paste into your original question , the result of `dput(head(20))`